# having a error with an api in web scrapping

Tags: html, json, api, web-scraping

i was web scrapping a website and the website had a hidden api to web scrape from so when i web scraped the api it returns to me this error and it doesn't give me the data that it have.

> code": "401.1.1",
> "message": "Failed to resolve API Key variable Verify-API-Key"

i was web scrapping a website and the website had a hidden api to web scrape from so when i web scraped the api it returns to me this error and it doesn't give me the data that it have.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need an API key to access the API freely, I don't think this is a bug but rather the intended behaviour.